# Java отрисовка фигур из очереди

Tags: java, ооп

Есть фрейм, на нем кнопка и панель JPanel. На JPanel рисуем фигуры. 
Это фрейм:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    ((Canvas)canvas).shape = new Rect();
}
```

Это код Canvas:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Canvas extends javax.swing.JPanel {

public Shape shape = null;
Queue myQueue = new Queue();

public Canvas(){
    super();   
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g){ 
        g.setColor(Color.white);                    
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());  
        if (shape != null) {
            shape.color = new Color((int)(Math.random() * 256), (int)(Math.random() * 256), (int)(Math.random() * 256));
            myQueue.addShape(shape);
            System.out.println("shape " + shape);
            for (int i = myQueue.getSize; i>-1; --i){
                shape = myQueue.getShape(i);
                shape.paint(g);
            }
        }
        try {
            shape = shape.getClass().newInstance();
            } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Canvas.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } 
        repaint();    
}
}
```

Shape:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Point;

public abstract class Shape {
public int x1, y1, x2, y2;  
public Color color;   
public String name = "Shape";

public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(color);
    draw(g);
}

public abstract void draw(Graphics g); 

/**
 *
 * @param evt
 */
public void MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
}

}
```

Rect:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JToggleButton;

public class Rect extends Shape {

@Override
public void draw(Graphics g){
    g.fillRect(100, 100, 100, 100);
}

}
```

Queue:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Queue {
public ArrayList<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<>();
public Shape nowshapes = null;
int getSize;

public void addShape(Shape newshapes){
    shapes.add(newshapes);
    nowshapes = newshapes;
}

public Shape getShape(int i){
    return shapes.get(i);
}

public void getSize(){
    getSize = shapes.size();
}
}
```

Собственно, в чем трабл: класс shape не переопределяется. Фигура заносится в очередь только один раз, когда в первый раз щелкаешь на кнопку. Т.е. дальнейшие нажатия на кнопку ни к чему не приводят
Как исправить?

Comment: Давайте начнем с формулировки задачи. Пока представленный код при нажатии на кнопку создает новый `Rect` и присваивает его полю. Потом, когда случается `paint()`, объект из поля получает случайный цвет и кладется в `myQueue`. Затем первый объект в `myQueue` рисуется (поскольку `getSize` в `for` - это неинициализированное поле класса, равное 0),  создается и складывается в `canvas.shape` новый `Rect`, и процесс бесконечно повторяется вызовом `repaint()`. Для чего все это?

Comment: Сейчас понял, что getSize не инициализирован. К чему это? Есть очередь фигур, куда можно добавлять фигуры. Эта очередь при repaint() постоянно выводится.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот неоптимизированное решение:
Canvas:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
public class Canvas extends javax.swing.JPanel {
public Shape shape = null;
Queue myQueue = new Queue();

public Canvas(){
super();   
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g){ 
        g.setColor(Color.white);                    
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());  
        System.out.println("myQueue.getSize: " + myQueue.getSize);
        if (shape != null) {
            shape.color = new Color((int)(Math.random() * 256), (int)(Math.random() * 256), (int)(Math.random() * 256));
            myQueue.addShape(shape);
            System.out.println("shape " + shape);
            for (int i = myQueue.getSize-1; i>-1; --i){
                //System.out.println("Я в форе и I: " + i);
                shape = myQueue.getShape(i);
                shape.paint(g);
                shape = null;
            }
            shape = null;
        }
        if (myQueue.getSize>0) {
            for (int i = myQueue.getSize-1; i>-1; --i){
                //System.out.println("Я в форе и I: " + i);
                shape = myQueue.getShape(i);
                shape.paint(g);
                shape = null;
            }
        }
        repaint();  
}
}
```

Queue:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Queue {
public ArrayList<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<>();
public Shape nowshapes = null;
int getSize = 0;

public void addShape(Shape newshapes){
    shapes.add(newshapes);
    nowshapes = newshapes;
    ++getSize;
}

public Shape getShape(int i){
    return shapes.get(i);
}

/*public void getSize(){
    getSize = shapes.size();
}*/
}
```